# How to use count and orderBy on eloquent multiple relationship fields?

Tags: php, eloquent, sql-order-by, relationship

What I'm trying to do is setup a server side configuration for a table data. So I have a model `CounterLog` that has 3 relationships set [`belongsTo`] `category`, `location`, `user`. I want a query to filter all `CounterLog` data including relationships, with `offset`, `limit` and `orderBy` methods set and in the same time retrieve all the filtered rows ignoring `offset` and `limit`. Here is what I managed until now and maybe understand better what I want:

```
$search_query = function($q) use ($search) {
    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
};

$query = CounterLog::where('created_at', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
->orWhereHas('category', $search_query)
->orWhereHas('location', $search_query)
->orWhereHas('user', $search_query);

$logs = $query->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
$logs_total = $query->offset(0)->count();
```

In the last line I'm using `$query->offset(0)` because for some reason if `offset` is set to a number `$logs_total` becomes 0. I'm not sure this is the proper way to do it.. but even like this I have no idea how to use `orderBy` for ex. `category.name`.

I know I can always use raw queries in eloquent but I want to know if there is a way to use ORM and relationships. I would really appreciate if you could help me with this..cuz the struggle is real.

Thanks a lot :)

---

Apparently I haven't got a solution with ORM so I did it with "raw" queries:

```
$query = $this->db->table('counter_logs')
                ->leftJoin('categories', 'counter_logs.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->leftJoin('locations', 'counter_logs.location_id', '=', 'locations.id')
                ->leftJoin('users', 'counter_logs.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                ->where('counter_logs.created_at', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('categories.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('locations.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                ->orWhere('users.name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
                ->select('counter_logs.id as id', 'categories.name as category', 'locations.name as location', 'users.name as user', 'counter_logs.created_at as date'); 

$json['total'] = $query->count();
$logs = $query->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->orderBy($sort, $order)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to swap statements:

```
$logs_total = $query->count();
$logs = $query->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
```

Or clone base query, like this:

```
$total_count_query = clone $query;
$logs = $query->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
$logs_total = $total_count_query->count();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,I don't know why I haven t tried this, swapping the statements works fine. Any idea how to solve the orderBy problem?